# Is it required to have WiFi connection to finish a resetting process?

Tags: windows-8

I bought a PC, an Aspire V5 to be precise. I am trying to reset my PC as new in my office. I noticed that almost all programs use WiFi connection. I need to go  home. And I want to carry my PC with me. So I am afraid to lose the Internet connection and produce a mistake while PC is resetting. My question is: do I need a WiFi connection or Internet connection to finish the resetting?

Comment: No you wont...
But, You'll definitely need it for app and windows set up after the reset has finished...But that thing can wait until you hook up to WiFi(unless your battery runs out before that)

Comment: PS: Please use correct grammar and spellings.

Answer (score 0):

You should not get any problem with resetting.Your pc does not need internet to reset.